# What is the maximum length of a prepared statement?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a mySQL stored procedure that is executing a lot of inserts.
Since performance was being bad, I decided not to Insert in every loop rather than build a string for the INSERT and in the end of the procedure I would do just one big INSERT for all the values with a prepared statement.

The problem is that my statement will be bigger than a VARCHAR. It would have to be TEXT.

The question is: Can I do that? Or does a prepared statement have to be VARCHAR?
What is the maximum length of a prepared statement?

Comment: For what it's worth: maximum length of VARCHAR = 65535 bytes; maximum length of TEXT = 65535 bytes.

Comment: What about batch-updating? Execute multiple insert statements (each a prepared-statement), and batch apply them for example after 10 inserts.

Comment: I chose the option of a Temporary Table. I insert everything in there and in the end I have just one INSERT INTO mytable SELECT * FROM mytemp; It improves the performance dramatically. The best option performance wise would be randiel's answer since I read that loading data from a file is the most optimized batch insert option in mysql. Also @BillKarwin Your first comment basically answers my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **[LOAD DATA](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/load-data.html)**. It's the option with the best performance when making a lot of inserts in mySQL, you can modify your input data as well.

Answer (score 0):

Check about: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/packet-too-large.html - this actual limit on single query

but your problem looks deeper, if you need to perform too many inserts, you need to prepare single insert statement, and in loop bind values to it and execute one by one

to speed up this process you will need to set autocommit to off, but then you will have next problem: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-restrictions.html

> InnoDB has a limit of 1023 concurrent transactions that have created undo records by modifying data.

and [innodb_log_file_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_log_file_size)

this both setting will limit your transaction size, so basically you need to add commit each Nth row (instead of each 1 row), Nth is better to determine programmatic

UPDATE: check comment from @BillKarwin - basically we can say that there is no limit on transaction size

Comment: That's not what that limit means; it's not a limit on the number of statements per transaction. It's a limit on the number of transactions (not statements) occupying space in the rollback segment. Anyway, the limit was increased 128x higher in MySQL 5.5 and later, and in MySQL 5.6 it's configurable up to 128x1023. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-restrictions.html

Comment: A small `innodb_log_fize_size` does not limit the scope of a transaction. Uncommitted changes will flush to the tablespace if the log fills up, and then space in the log file can be overwritten. This means if you do a huge transaction and then roll back, it has to recover previous versions of pages from the rollback segment and then flush them too.  Rollback of a huge transaction can therefore be quite expensive, so you're right in recommending periodic commits.

Comment: @BillKarwin yeap, you're right, I supposed mysql handles log file as "undo log"

Comment: The log file is a *redo* log, to reconstruct changes lost in a crash. The *undo* information is in the rollback segment of the tablespace.